# How to execute .Net Core 2.0 Console App using Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, taskscheduler

I have one Console App which is created using `asp.net Core 2.0` in `VS2017`. Now I want to run this application on particular time period repeatedly (like service). So I have tried this using `Windows Task Scheduler` but when we create task using `Task Scheduler` it ask for `.exe` file of Console app. (please check below pic)
[image]

But as you can see that When we create Console App using .Net Core 2.0 there will no `.exe` file under bin/debug folder. [image]
Anyone have idea that how to schedule a .net Core 2.0 console app using Windows Task Scheduler ?
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: could you just run "dotnet" as the target, with the rest as the parameters? hard to track in terms of processes, but it should work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just call `dotnet` and pass in dll you wish to run as argument. You can either specify the full path in the argument or set the path where your dll resides in the "Start in" field. You should use the published dll and NOT the development dll that gets created in the project's bin folder.

[image: Task Scheduler Start DLL]

Comment: dotnet might not be installed.

Comment: @AgentFire If dotnet is not installed, you'll have a bit of trouble running a console app at all.